# scala future seq map case for at least one not timeout

Tags: scala, match, case, settimeout, future

I have to send out 10 queries to 10 different site respectively with a timeout in scala code on play framework. There could be some websites doesn't return within timeout window(The query to that site timeout). If some sites(at least one site) return response, I will need to proceed with those response(s). My code can work but it is very cumbersome. Any better way?

```
val timeout = 8.seconds
 Async {
    val resFuture = for {   
       response1 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url1, timeout)
       response2 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url2, timeout)
       response3 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url3, timeout)
       response4 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url4, timeout)
       response5 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url5, timeout)
       response6 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url6, timeout)
       response7 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url7, timeout)
       response8 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url8, timeout)
       response9 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url9, timeout)
       response10 <- Future firstCompletedOf Seq(WS.url10, timeout)
 } yied(response1,response2,response3,response4,response5,response6,response7,response8,response9, response10)

 Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(resFuture, timeout)).map {
  case: (Some(resp1), Some(resp2),Some(resp3),Some(resp4),Some(resp5),Some(resp6),Some(resp7),Some(resp8),Some(resp9),Some(resp10)) => { process all 10 reponses}
  case: (Some(resp1), Some(resp2),Some(resp3),Some(resp4),Some(resp5),Some(resp6),Some(resp7),Some(resp8),Some(resp9),None) => { process all 9 responses}
  case: (Some(resp1), Some(resp2),Some(resp3),Some(resp4),Some(resp5),Some(resp6),Some(resp7),Some(resp8),None,None) => { process all 8 responses }
  ....
  I will need to enumerate all the possible combinations which will be handres cases. 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I would advice you to use the "Aggregator pattern" of Akka framework. Using actors you will reduce your boilerplate code.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html

Check the docs, there are great examples, so I won't copy-paste them here. 
Also I saw few blog entries regarding this pattern, but not sure if I can post links on a private blogs, so it won't be treated as an ad.

Comment: I read the doc. It seems I have to redesign my code. Is there a better way to have case like: case : Seq() => then I can enumerate the Seq() and handle all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `WS.urlX` are `Future[Something]` and that `timeout` is a `Future[Something]` that will be completed with a `TimeoutException` after Y time.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val results = Future.sequence(Seq(WS.url1, WS.url2, WS.url3, WS.url4, WS.url5, WS.url6, WS.url7, WS.url8, WS.url9, WS.url10).map(
  // For every of these Futures, fail them if timeout completes first, and lift their result to Some on success and a None on failure
  f => Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f, timeout)).map(Some(_)).recover({case _ => None})
))
```

This will give you a `Future[Seq[Some[Something]]]` where if an element is `Some` you got a result within the timeout, and a `None` if there was an error or if it timed out.

And now you can simply do:

```
for {
  seq <- results
  result <- seq
} result match {
  case Some(r) => doSomethingWith(r)
  case None => doSomethingOnFailure()
}
```